# URL patterns for REST in Microservices

Tags: rest, url, design-patterns, microservices

We are thinking about the best URL scheme for our (mostly) RESTful microservices. Each service has his own context. A service for hashtag (like Instagram) specific logic does all things that connect to hashtags.
A user service that does all the handling of registered users and so on.

So we thought we start every URL with /api and then the context of every service. In this case for example /api/hashtag oder /api/user

The problem is that those services have the same name as the "core" resource. The user service has a resource that lists all users for example so the URL must be something like /api/user/user.
Same goes for hashtags. There is a resource in that service that lists all hashtags. So the URL must be /api/hashtag/hashtag.

And now you get the problem: The "core" resource sounds exactly like the service. And we are looking for a good solution for that. Are there any best practices for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why must the url have those patterns? I don't really see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic behind url naming is [Resource Oriented Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource-oriented_architecture) (ROA). i.e. Resource Hierarchy.

Let's take an example from your question. You have a user service. I assume that there you take `user` as the `root resource`.

So Let's define what a user looks like. For an example I'll take it like this.

```
User

     | - code

     | - name

     | - cars
```

Here I assume that a user can have a **code**, **name** and **some cars** (can be more than one).

And now let's see how we can see a car.

```
Car

     | - number

     | - make

     | - model

     | - year
```

Now you can define a json object for a user like this.

```
{
    "code": "001A",
    "name": "alice",
    "cars": [
        {
            "number": "ab123",
            "make": "toyota",
            "model": "corolla",
            "year": 2015
        },
        {
            "number": "we345",
            "make": "nissan",
            "model": "sunny",
            "year": 2017
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I wanna provide an endpoint to retrieve all the users I would give an endpoint like this.

```
/api/user-service/users
```

Note that ***users*** (-- plural), simply because I can have more than one user. It would produce a response like this..

```
[
    {
        "code": "001A",
        "name": "alice",
        "cars": [
            {
                "make": "toyota",
                "model": "corolla",
                "year": 2015
            },
            {
                "make": "nissan",
                "model": "sunny",
                "year": 2017
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "001B",
        "name": "bob",
        "cars": [
            {
                "make": "toyota",
                "model": "yaris",
                "year": 2016
            },
            {
                "make": "bmw",
                "model": "318i",
                "year": 2017
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And if we need an endpoint to retrieve data for a specific user, I would give and endpoint like this.

```
/api/user-service/users/{user-code}
```

Example

```
/api/user-service/users/001A
```

So it would produce a response like this.

```
{
    "code": "001A",
    "name": "alice",
    "cars": [
        {
            "number": "ab123",
            "make": "toyota",
            "model": "corolla",
            "year": 2015
        },
        {
            "number": "we345",
            "make": "nissan",
            "model": "sunny",
            "year": 2017
        }
    ]
}
```

And if we want an endpoint to retrieve all the cars of a given user, it would be like this.

```
/api/user-service/users/{user-code}/cars
```

Note that **cars** (--plural)

Example

```
/api/user-service/users/001A/cars
```

So it would produce a response like this.

```
[
    {
        "number": "ab123",
        "make": "toyota",
        "model": "corolla",
        "year": 2015
    },
    {
        "number": "we345",
        "make": "nissan",
        "model": "sunny",
        "year": 2017
    }
]
```

I hope you get the basic understanding about REST url naming conventions.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good practice to name the service as /api/serviceName/resource
Having said that your problem is the service name. One thing we used to do was add Service to the name. Say UserService or OrderService. I have also seen name as oms (for Order Management Service stand in) ims etc.
You can have order-management/order or user-management/user.

If it is an internal api you can also go ahead with some code names for your services.

Or you can just let go of the service name. Your routing logic might swell but for external clients they really don't care whom they are talking to. You can keep /api/order or /api/user

Comment: Downvoted because: Personal opinion (not citing relevant sources) while the OP explicitly asked for best practices; missing the plural (see the accepted answer); not explaining why the URLs could/should be different for "internal apis" (I disagree because it would be harder to understand for no good reason)